# Asking focussed "How to" Questions?

Tags: discussion

If you have a specific technical problem, but don't know where to start, is it ok to ask a `How to ...` question on SO? Alternatively, is this format of question better suited to one of the other sub forums? I would have thought that as they are often fairly objective and specific. For example, `How to build a cross platform mobile app with a Microsoft Azure Backend`, might prompt a an answer pointing to Xamarin and some specific tutorials on msdn.

Are these types of questions allowed and up-vote worthy?

Comment: Agree with others that this is rarely a good type of question, but there are exceptions.  Provided that 1) It hasn't been asked before 2) It's narrow enough in scope 3) It's very clear what is being asked, and 4) It's something that is not so simple that it doesn't need a Q/A, and it's not so complicated that it's too broad for a Q/A.  Just one example of an exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c

Answer (score 6):

> Are these types of questions allowed and up-vote worthy?

Rarely.

*How to ...* questions mostly have the imminent problem of being off-topic because they come out *too broad*.

Better is to show some particular code context that was tried out, and ask about the problems observed with it in particular.

Answer (score 4):

Asking focused questions is certainly allowed. However, your given example,

> How to build a cross platform mobile app with a Microsoft Azure Backend

is *not* focused at all. It is too broad, because there are potentially numerous ways in which a mobile app can make use of Azure services, and furthermore Azure is composed of a number of different services, and apps can use any number or combination of them. For example, while this question might prompt an answer about Xamarin, it might also prompt an answer about Apache Cordova, or one about Appcelerator.

A focused question would be one that asks how to implement a specific Azure service in a specific portion of a mobile app using specific technologies. That would be very well on-topic for the site provided you have shown your research, etc (keyword being "shown").

You don't have to know where to start, but at the very least you'll want to know your specific goal, for example "How do I implement cross-platform toast notifications using Xamarin" or "How do I authenticate users via Facebook and Twitter via Azure". These are examples of questions that are focused.

πάντα ῥεῖ is right in that how-to questions have a tendency to fall into "too broad" territory. It is difficult to write a focused how-to question, and normally so. But it is possible.